# "URL with custom scheme" in iOS data and "URL" in Android data in facebook

Tags: android, ios, facebook, codenameone, facebook-invite-friends

I have an app which is available now on both iOS and Android.

- The iOS_app_url like https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/.../id...
- The Android_app_url like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=...

Now I would like to add the "invite friends" function by calling the https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/social/FacebookConnect.html#inviteFriends function to allow the player to invite his friends to install my app. I enter the https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host site and select my app there. However I don't know how to fill below things:

```
"App Link Name"                       : simply enter the app name? 
"URL with custom scheme" (in iOS Data): should enter something like "myapp://" but I don't know to to configure "myapp" in CodenameOne project.
"URL" (in Android Data)               : ???
"URL" (in Web data)                   : ???
```

Is there any place to put the iOS_app_url or android_app_url mentioned above?

Anyone can help? thanks.

Comment: Could you please tell me what you did for your url with custom scheme (but my app is not publish yet) and there is no clear guide shows me how to add Facebook invite to my app and it is not publish yet. Help will much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The URL should be in the form of `myappURL://calledFromFB` this will then be launched by Facebook when trying to launch your app.

Check out the `ios.urlScheme` build hint and the section titled "Passing Launch Arguments To The App": https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html

This allows your app to open with information related to the invite.

Comment: Thanks Shai. What I should enter for the URL in the "Android Data" part?

Comment: You can enter the exact same URL. That's designed to allow you to have two different URL's one for each platform which isn't necessary here.